# StackPanel ZIndex not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to achieve something like this, where there is that visible border (left of 'Market summary') vertically.

I have a grid, two columns (the left part = picture, name, email, listbox) and right part everything else). I tried to show that border by bringing the StackPanel which is found on the left column to the front using Panel.Zindex but that didn't do anything.

```
    <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="1"  Grid.Column="0">

        <materialDesign:ColorZone  Height="100"  Mode="PrimaryMid">
            <Border  Padding="8">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="48" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.014,0.003" Margin="0,0,104,0">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="RandomPic.jpg" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>

                    <TextBlock Text="UsernameX" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="EmailY" ></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

        </materialDesign:ColorZone>


        <ListBox  Background="#FAFAFA"  x:Name="DemoItemsListBox">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <TextBlock> What's going on</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>What's going on</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>What's going on</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>What's going on</TextBlock>
            </ListBox.Items>

        </ListBox>

    </StackPanel>


    <StackPanel  Panel.ZIndex="0"   Grid.Column="1">

        <materialDesign:ColorZone Panel.ZIndex="0"    Height="60" Mode="PrimaryMid" />
        <!--
        <dragablz:TabablzControl BorderBrush="#4CAF50" BorderThickness="0" Height="56" >

            <TabItem  Header="                 Ordre de mission                " IsSelected="True">
                <TextBlock><Run Text="Hello World"/></TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab No. 2">
                <TextBlock><Run Text="We Have Tearable Tabs!"/></TextBlock>
            </TabItem>


       </dragablz:TabablzControl>
-->

 <ContentControl></ContentControl>

    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Your issue is unclear? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Setting Zindex in the StackPanel doesn't bring Listbox or ColorZone to front for some reason.

Comment: Are you referring to the first StackPanel with a ZIndex of 1? The ColorZone and ListBox are chilren of this StackPanel.

Comment: yes I'm referring to that StackPanel. I know they are children but I want them to be brought to front compared to StackPanel 2 (Zindex = 0). so Basically anything in the stackpanel should be brought to front. Doesn't my code make sense in that case?

Comment: StackPanel 2 is in another grid column, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, It's written in the code. One is in Column 0 and the other is in 1.

Comment: So why would they overlap?

Comment: I want to have that border you see on the right of the profile picture. So I thought that by bringing StackPanel to front using ZIndex which is found on Grid's Column 0, that should do it.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/aGRgzx5.png I just want to make this border show. and I thought that by bringing the left column to front, It will show.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF StackPanel doesn't have a border so bringing it to the front is not going to make one appear.

You would have to add your own either behind it in the same grid column or next to it by inserting a thin column and putting either a Border or Separator control in it. If putting it in the same column, you may need to adjust the StackPanel's margin so that it doesn't obscure the border.

i.e.

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Gray"/>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0">

    <materialDesign:ColorZone  Height="100"  Mode="PrimaryMid">
        <Border  Padding="8">
            <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="48" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.014,0.003" Margin="0,0,104,0">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="RandomPic.jpg" />
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>

                <TextBlock Text="UsernameX" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="EmailY" ></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

    </materialDesign:ColorZone>


    <ListBox  Background="#FAFAFA"  x:Name="DemoItemsListBox">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <TextBlock> What's going on</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>What's going on</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>What's going on</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>What's going on</TextBlock>
        </ListBox.Items>

    </ListBox>

</StackPanel>
```